# How to find out whether graph supports transactions?

Tags: tinkerpop

When I call `graph.tx()` for TinkerGraph I get exception that graph does not support transactions. But how can I check if graph supports them or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `GraphFeatures` to determine that:

```
graph.features().graph().supportsTransactions()
```

which will return `true` if transactions are supported. You can read more about `GraphFeatures` [here](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#_features) and more about transactions [here](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#transactions).

Comment: Argh, StackOverflow can be very irritating sometimes. Reviewers did not like the answer as just a single string `graph.features().graph().supportsTransactions()`. And I did not get a single notification about their comments, so my own answer was silently deleted.

WTF.

Comment: yeah - a lot of Gremlin questions/answers get a bit of over-sensitive reviews sometimes as folks aren't always aware of the TinkerPop ecosystem. your answer made perfect sense to me :)

Answer (score 0):

`graph.features().graph().supportsTransactions()`

Comment: @achal This DOES provide the answer.